# Unterminated string constant in Google Map API using PHP

Tags: php, string, constant-expression

i have problem with unterminated string constant.

here is my code in PHP:

```
'html' => '<div><table><td><tr><img src="' . "http://www.simbawave.com/_lib/file/img/hotel/$FolderHotel/$NamaFile" . '"width="200" height="200" /></tr><tr><p><b>'.$Hotel."</b></p></tr></td><td>$Alamat</td></table></div>",
```

and here is the HTML source (result, not all, it will be too long)

```
markers[8] = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: "http://www.simbawave.com/MapBlueIcon/villa.png",
    title: "Bali Dynasty Resort",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.747509, 115.16764),
    map: map
});
infos[8] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<div><table><td><tr><img src=\"http://www.simbawave.com/_lib/file/img/hotel/HO-00009/depan2web.jpg\"width=\"200\" height=\"200\" /></tr><tr><p><b>Bali Dynasty Resort</b></p></tr></td><td> Jln. Kartika Po Box 2047
Tuban 80361
South Kuta
Bali - Indonesia</td></table></div>"
});
```

if i remove the variable `$Alamat`, it will be fine, no problem. but i ad $Alamat, i don't have any idea what's wrong with my PHP code.

The value of `$Alamat` is like that (string/varchar):

```
Jln. Kartika Po Box 2047
Tuban 80361
South Kuta
```

But in HTML view, it is shown only:

> Jln. Kartika Po Box 2047

I thought there should be some characters are missing when passing to HTML.

```
Tuban 80361
South Kuta
Bali - Indonesia</td></table></div>
```

I thought those are the characters were not passed and make this error because the `$Alamat` contains multi lines not a single line while `$Hotel` contains a single line of string.

Anyone know how to make this varchar multi lines can be used in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

If you can try to not rely of PHP line breaks.  Put in some `<br />`'s since you are passing HTML to the content anyways.

I too am having a similar issue, however, my HTML is properly formatted...    I'll update this answer once I can get my issue figured out :), but for now, do a `str_replace` and replace all the PHP linebreaks `\r` & `\n` with a `<br />`

I have fixed my own issue, and wanted to share what I did with you.

```
function FormatMapContent($str){
    return str_replace(array('.', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $str); 
}
```

Wrap your `InfoWindow` content with that, and you should be good to go.

HTH
~Kevin